# Keeping the Android NFC onTagDiscovered callback thread alive

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, nfc

I have defined the required class and overridden the `onTagDiscovered` method to handle NFC events. Works as expected.

```
public class NfcReader implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {
@Override
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
// handle tag data
   }
}
```

What I've noticed, and can't find any documents that explain this, this callback is run in its own thread.  I'm not sure when this thread is created but if in `onTagDiscovered` I do:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Get ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

It will return an arbitrary ID each time a new tag is discovered. I assume this means it's running in a separate thread that is not the main thread.

Can anyone shed some light on the lifecycle of this thread?

My issue is I have some asynchronous tasks that I need to do between the messages I need to send to the tag. What I previously did (in a modified example project) was start a looper and message handler in the `onTagDiscovered` and sent messages to indicate when my asynchronous tasks were done and tag communication could continue.

```
public class NfcReader implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {
    private NfcV nfcvTag;

    @Override
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        // handle initial tag discovery
        nfcvTag = NfcV.get(tag);

        ...

        // initiate long running task that needs to be 
        // complete before we can continue talking to tag
        ...


        if(Looper.myLooper() == null)
            Looper.prepare();

        mHandlerNfc = new Handler(Looper.myLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // process incoming messages 

                ...

                // continue NFC transcieve.

                response = nfcvTag.transceive(cmd);
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

But for whatever reason, in this new project, I'm inconsistently getting errors saying I'm trying to send messages to a thread that no longer exists.  Sometimes my messages go through and the handler gets them, sometimes they don't due to the thread not being around anymore.

Shouldn't the looper keep the thread alive?

Is there a better way to do this than to try and keep this thread alive?  I did this assuming that it was what was needed to continue to transceive with a tag.  Would it be possible to continue a transceive from a previously discovered tag from the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

The callback thread is supposed to be short-lived. If you want to do longer operations, you should use another thread instead. You could, for instance, spawn a separate worker thread, post some action to the UI thread or to some other looper thread/executor that you created before the `onTagDiscovered()` is invoked.